# Ionic 2 : Push notification iOS - Export in .p12

Tags: ios, macos, ionic2, keychain

I try to build an Ionic 2 app and I have some problem to export certificate in .p12

My certificate is in "session" of the left side of my Keychain Access, but I can't export my certificate.

I have this :

[image]

Any idea to solve that ?